# How to run all tests in given package?

Tags: java, junit4, test-suite

I wrote a suite:

```
package com;

import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClasspathSuite.ClassnameFilters({"com.mycompany.*"})
@ClasspathSuite.IncludeJars(true)
public class AllTests {
}
```

where `com.mycompany.*` is a package, which contains a lot of nested packages and test classes inside.

I includes sources from [`takari-cpsuite`](https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite) in my project inside `test` subfolder.

I got my IDE recognized this class as a suite and displayed an icon near it to run tests.

Unfortunately, when I run it, I get:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

What is incorrect here?